# Spring security: difference between WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

These two classes:

```
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter
```

seem to do the same thing to me. They both provide different methods `configure(...)` to customize WebSecurity, such as to configure `UserDetailsService`. In some examples found on the internet, I saw that both classes are extended (like this one, http://ryanjbaxter.com/2015/01/06/securing-rest-apis-with-spring-boot/):

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

and

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

**but in some** example, only `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was needed (extended).

I am not sure about the difference between the two? What one can do that the other cannot? Or if they are both needed, then which of them is for what aspect of Spring security?

The only difference I've seen is that `@EnableWebSecurity` is often annotated above class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, but not in the class that extends `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter`

=============**EXPERIMENT**==================

I tried deleting the class that extends `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter`, and carrying the code related to UserDetailsService to the class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (See the link above for the actual code), and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is used to create the `FilterChainProxy`
refer to this [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html) as to `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` is used as `SecurityConfigurer`that can be used to easily build in memory authentication, LDAP authentication, JDBC based authentication, adding UserDetailsService, and adding AuthenticationProvider's. refer to this [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.html) hope this helps!

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  can be used to configure in memory auth, LDAP, JDBC too. Both classes have method `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` which is used to do just that.

Comment: In my previous projects i use the `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` to configure the global configurations then i used the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to override those configurations for the specific routes with different configs

Comment: can you give some examples for 1) global configurations, and 2) some configs specific to routes? Thanks

Comment: @Simo did you figure out the difference?